# How can I get this text-shadow to work with IE filters?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, shadow

I need to get the , , and  tags on my site: http://designsweeter.com/
...to work in IE 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.

Is there a javascript plugin to get IE to understand the text-shadow property?

If not, is it possible to do through IE filters like `shadow()`? Is there a converter online that will convert my text-shadow to IE filters?

If none of the above, is there an alternative?

Here are my headers tags:

```
h1{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-shadow:0 3px 0 #444,0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8),0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    font-size:30px;text-align:center;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:10px;
}

h1 a:active{
    position:relative;
    font-weight:400;
    top:2px;
    text-shadow:0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

h2{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
    opacity:.9;
    font-weight:200;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:-1px -2px 1px #000;
}

h3{
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #000;
    opacity:.7;
    font-size:15px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use JavaScript and apply the shadow, won't it be easy to use the css directly. Using css would cause less reflow/paint events. Use the simple 
filter: shadow(color=#FF0000)

Comment: I'd like to know how to add multiple shadows to the element to get the nice effect I've got going on with the headers.

Comment: What is filter strength, and how can I set xoffset and yoffset?

Answer (score 0):

This here should work: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/javascript/text-shadow-in-ie-with-jquery/

Comment: I need to include multiple text shadows to one element. I didn't find it on that page. Do you know if it supports multiple text-shadows? If so, how. Thanks again!

Comment: Multiple? I'm afraid don't know... Couldn't it be possible to use images (text-shadows are iffy because browsers are insanely inconsistent with them)? I'd make a wild assumption that the shadows aren't being used liberally, so images could be used to sparingly replace text.

Comment: I need the text for SEO purposes. :/

Comment: If my entire site was in images, I'd rank pretty low.

Comment: Well, presumably if your entire site has to be shadows in the first place... Headers alone, assuming it'd be used fairly sparingly, would probably be fine, throw in some good alt texts, etc. Overal, though, I wouldn't personally recommend using text shadows at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/examples/css-drop-shadows.html#ie_win_and_safari